# App crashes on its very first run when using Firebase with onesignal

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, onesignal

lately, i have upgraded my firebase and onesignal dependencies to the latest versions, but a strange thing happens, after the app installs for the first time, and i open it, it directly crushes after 1-2 seconds, but when you open it up again the second time, it behaves normally without crushing.

here is my  gradle(app-level):

```
        apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.11.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammed.skyquestionbank"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : 'my_id',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]

        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.9'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.zekapp.library:progreswheelview:1.1.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and here the root level

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
      maven {
          url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
      }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and Here is the crush log:

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-11 00:26:41.282 5157-5157/com.example.mohammed.skyquestionbank      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mohammed.skyquestionbank, PID: 5157
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzac()Lcom/google      /firebase/iid/zzap; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzap; or its super     classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzap' appears in /data/app/com.example.mohammed.skyquestionbank-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)             atcom.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
10-11 00:26:41.288 1146-1146/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1146:     eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: Your dependencies are very outdated. Please update them.

Comment: Make sure your google-services classpath is also up-to-date in your root gradle config.

Comment: @TheWanderer sorry my mistake, see updated. it was my old gradle dependencies i copied.

Comment: its up-to date, im using latest version in everything, i added my root gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i solved the problem by myself, there seems to be a problem with the latest version of firebase-core and firebase-auth 16.0.4 as they just recently released this october.
i had to downgrade them to 16.0.3 to match with my firebase-database 16.0.3. and the crush got away.

Comment: those version numbers do not need to match exactly.

Comment: @MartinZeitler that is what everybody suggest if you look to other answers. but anyway in my case it seemed to be the newest version, that is why downgrading from 16.0.4 to 16.0.3 solved the problem

Comment: it might work together with `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0`.